# Why Hibernate MassIndexer says indexing completed but really it isn't completed

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am trying to index large data(13.5 million records with association to 7-8 tables) in elastic search using MassIndexer. It shown message that it indexed all the records after 39.08%. I am getting the same issue in local and production, the percentage varies for every execution.

```
fullTextEntityManager
                .createIndexer(XYZ.class)
                .batchSizeToLoadObjects(500).cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).threadsToLoadObjects(2).idFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
                .startAndWait();
```

Log:

```
23:05:25,338 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-2)  INFO SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor:90 - HSEARCH000031: Indexing speed: 1085.105591 documents/second; progress: 39.08%
23:05:25,339 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-2)  INFO SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor:87 - HSEARCH000030: 5322450 documents indexed in 4904960 ms
23:05:25,339 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-2)  INFO SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor:90 - HSEARCH000031: Indexing speed: 1085.115845 documents/second; progress: 39.08%
23:05:25,339 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-2)  INFO SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor:87 - HSEARCH000030: 5322500 documents indexed in 4904961 ms
23:05:25,339 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-2)  INFO SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor:90 - HSEARCH000031: Indexing speed: 1085.125854 documents/second; progress: 39.08%
23:05:36,103 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-3) DEBUG request:194 - HSEARCH400082: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to path '/xyz/_forcemerge' with query parameters {} in 16734ms. Response had status 200 'OK'.
23:05:37,666 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-3) DEBUG request:194 - HSEARCH400082: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to path '/xyz/_flush' with query parameters {} in 1562ms. Response had status 200 'OK'.
23:05:37,668 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-3) DEBUG request:194 - HSEARCH400082: Executed Elasticsearch HTTP POST request to path '/xyz/_refresh' with query parameters {} in 1ms. Response had status 200 'OK'.
23:05:37,668 (main)  INFO SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor:78 - HSEARCH000028: Reindexed 13618954 entities
```

It should show indexing completed only after indexing all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your log](https://github.com/chaitut715/share/raw/master/mass-indexer.log) clearly shows there are errors during mass indexing, which wasn't mentioned in your initial post.

You periodically get errors like this:

```
10:48:28,125 (Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch transport thread-2) ERROR LogErrorHandler:71 - HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
Request: POST /_bulk with parameters {refresh=false}
Response: null
Subsequent failures:
    Entity com.example.model.XXXXXX  Id 855665929073643520  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork

org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
Request: POST /_bulk with parameters {refresh=false}
Response: null
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.work.impl.BulkWork.lambda$execute$1(BulkWork.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.Futures.lambda$handler$1(Futures.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClient$1.onFailure(DefaultElasticsearchClient.java:123)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onDefinitiveFailure(RestClient.java:605)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.retryIfPossible(RestClient.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.failed(RestClient.java:375)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.failed(BasicFuture.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:419)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:175)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:492)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:213)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    ... 11 more
```

While essentially means some indexing requests failed due to Elasticsearch taking too long to answer.

There could be many causes.

Your Hibernate Search configuration looks very conservative (only two threads), so I don't think you're putting too much stress on your Elasticsearch cluster.

I would suggest to double check your Elasticsearch setup (the Elasticsearch documentation probably provides some do's and don't's that could help).
Check that you have an appropriately sized Elasticsearch cluster, that servers are dimensioned appropriately, ...

You may also want to tune the `hibernate.search` configuration properties related to communication with the Elasticsearch cluster: the timeouts, the number of connections, ... See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration-configuration

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like [HSEARCH-3462](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3462), which was fixed in 6.0.0.Alpha2 but wasn't backported to 5.11.

Long story short: it's a logging problem, not an indexing problem. The last line that states that everything was reindexed is the one you should believe.

I will see if we can easily backport the fix to 5.10/5.11, but it might take some time until we release these branches again. Backport ticket (if you need to track progress): https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3622

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked elasticsearch documents count using /index/_count,  it's not matching with database records. In the log, there is only 12 mins gap between 39% and the last statement, it's impossible to index 8 million records during this time.

Comment: In the log, there is only 12 seconds gap. I mentioned as mins in the previous comment

Comment: I see. Then it's likely that something failed during indexing. Normally, exceptions are notified tot the ErrorHandler, which by default will log the exception at the `ERROR` level. Do you see anything of this sort? If not, check your custom error handler (if any), and check that the logger `org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler` is enabled at the ERROR level in your log4j configuration or equivalent.

Comment: No error on the console. I set the hibernate log to DEBUG level.
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.search=debug

Comment: At this point the only way I can see this scenario happen is if an `Error` was thrown: while indexing an entity, an `Error` was thrown (not an `Exception`, an `Error`), the `Error` was not caught, and ended up killing the thread. Did you have a look at the standard output/standard error too? Depending on your configuration, standard output/standard error might be redirected to different files than your logs (I know it can happen on Tomcat in particular, probably on other platforms as well). Then you might miss an `OutOfMemoryError` or similar being dumped to the standard output... ?

Comment: I wrote simple java program to test this indexing process and running in intellij. Configured 4gb memory to intellij and set the log level to debug and redirected log to a file. It stopped indexing as mentioned in the main post.Interesting thing is I couldn't see any error on the console/file. Log file size is 4gb. Any idea on why it didn't show OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: I'm not even sure there was an `OutOfMemoryError`, it's all conjectures at this point: the method `org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer#run` can only exit early if an exception or error happens, and if it's an exception it should be logged. So I assumed an error happened.

Comment: I suppose this reproducer of yours relies on a massive, private dataset and you can't share it with me. Maybe you could run your reproducer again, setting logger `org.hibernate.search.batchindexing` to TRACE (for execution information) and share the resulting log file? If it's really too large, you can set logger `org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor` to WARN to leave out the indexing progress statements in the log file. Ideally it would be great to have the console output, too.

Comment: There was no error on the console. I can share you log privately if it's fine for you. I enabled log, so it's size is 4gb.

Comment: Thanks, i will log as per your suggestion.

Comment: Please check [log file](https://github.com/chaitut715/share/raw/master/mass-indexer.log)